# Can I use a Mac Mini as a build/deployment server with React Native?

Tags: react-native

I've done some research on how to do this but haven't found exactly what I was looking for. In short, I'd like to continue to develop my react native app on my Windows PC, and use a Mac Mini for remote builds and deployment to my iOS device. Is there a good way to do this?

I know there are CI solutions such as Jenkins, but ideally I'd like to be able to build/deploy even faster without having to push commits. Similar to Hot Reloading, I'd like to make a change on my PC (Windows) and see it immediately on my iOS device, which I can do currently with an Android device plugged in to my PC today.

Maybe something like running the packager on my mac mini while making code changes from my PC.

Comment: I haven't used any of the other StackExchange communities. Would this question be better suited in a different community?

Comment: Did you find any solution/guide to this?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet...

Comment: Did you found a solution?

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, but having a shared folder between your windows and mac, and put all the code inside might work